# Fractional parts in base number systems other than base-10?

Tags: number-systems

A long-standing question I've asked myself over and over again is how one might express fractional parts of a whole in base number systems other than 10. Is it truly as simple as base-10's x/y system? Or is it even possible? If it is, how might a computer express a fractional part of, say, binary or hexidecimal?

Comment: I think that this link: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55744.html will be of help to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it should be as straightforward as x/y

for example 1/3 in base 10 would be 1/11 in binary

adding 1/3+ 1/3 =2/3 base 10 would be 1/11+1/11 = 10/11 in binary

adding 2/3+1/3 =1 should be 10/11+ 1/11= 11/11=1 in binary

Comment: Hmm... Interesting. I'll accept this answer for now- if anyone has anything else they'd like to add, feel free. Thanks.

Comment: This answer is not correct, $1.11 = 1*2^0 + 1*2^{-1}+1*2^{-2}$ this is analog to the decimal system where for example $1.57=1*10^0+5*10^{-1}+7*10^{-2}$

Comment: @Eliot - See my comment